# Adding M values to a shapefile so the distance along the line is displayed as a derived attribute in QGIS

Tags: qgis, m-values

I'm new to QGIS which I'm using to create data for a road network. I have a road network setup as a polyline shapefile, but need to identify the chainage long the network sections to use in other datasets. I have loaded a `PolylineM` shapefile and in that the distance along the line is given when I use the identify features tool as the derived attribute `Interpolated M`. I have tried using the '*Set M Value*' tool to create a new layer which stores the lengths as the M value, but can't get that to work so that it reports the distance along the line the same way the `PolylineM` shapefile does.

Does anyone know if this method would/should work, or how I can go about setting this up?